# Excel formula to sum all entries in a row if value of adjacent cell is equal to third cell

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

I need to build a formula that will sum the numbers in a series of cells only if the value of an adjacent cell is equal to the value of a third cell.

The latter two values are text.

In plain language, I want the formula to do this:

Look at the values in Sheet 2, Column C. Ignore the ones that aren't equal to the value in cell D3 on Sheet 1. For the ones that are equal to that value, grab the value in column Z of the same row. Add up all those values and spit out the sum into one cell.

EDIT: Thank you, I was not aware of the SUMIF function but was able to get it to work.

```
=SUMIF(DbT!BZ:BZ,'2013'!B4,DbT!S:S)
```

Comment: Welcome to Super User. This site is not a scripting service. We however help people who have attempted to solve an issue on their own and get stuck. Please [edit] your question to include what you've done to attempt this yourself. Include any formulas you are using or have tried.

Comment: Apologies @CharlieRB, will follow this standard in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SUMIF function is made for this purpose.  See Excel function help for more details on the 3 parameters:

```
SUMIF(range, criteria, [sum_range])
```

Sheet2!C:C = *range* (what your criteria is against)

Sheet1!D3 = *criteria* (what your range values must match)

Sheet2!Z:Z = *sum_range* (what you are adding up)

```
=SUMIF(Sheet2!C:C,Sheet1!D3,Sheet2!Z:Z)
```

Note, I'm assuming you mean **Column** C in your question, not Row C.  If not, please re-write.

Comment: I did mean Column C, thanks for catching that. Will try this and check back. Thank you!